# copying a protected file on an ntfs partition

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, mount, ntfs

dual booting Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with windows 10 and i cant read certain files sitting on an ntfs partition.

My goal is to copy the files to a separate folder *without* modifying the files, their permissions, or their owners.

trying to run `sudo cp -r ProtectedDirectory/ Backup/` results in `cp: error reading 'ProtectedDirectory/...': Permission denied` for almost every file in the directory.

How can I mount or in another way temporarily allow ubuntu to read the files within the directory without modifying them?

Comment: please do add an `ls -l` for the dir and a couple of files inside it And possibly the mount options

Comment: @Rinzwind all of the permissions for the files i cant read are `rwxrwxrwx 1 <user> <user> <size> May 8 2022`
im not using any custom mount options, just clicked on the disk in nautilus to mount it. I've tried a few others online, but none worked.